# Pandas TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' / 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the following pandas/sklearn algorithm to predict the movie genre based on words occuring in the movie. Find the dataset [here](https://tumde-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alexander_farr_tum_de/EauYmDrHzclOiKghjUqjZsQBHKjbJj-zdnWlH7fgA1BDjg?e=bhLaFD)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data=pd.read_csv('movies.csv',sep=',');
df1 = data[["marri", "huh", "hous", "mother", "nice", "home", "miss", "play", "happi", "write","wouldnt","power", "captain", "ship", "weve", "move", "ship", "system", "world", "command", "three"]]
predicted_genre=data[["Genre"]]
X = np.c_[np.ones((df1.shape[0], 1)), df1]
predicted_genre = predicted_genre[:, np.newaxis]
```

Here, the error occurs but I included the code below since it is relevant for the second error:

```
theta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], 1))
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, predicted_genre.values.ravel())
parameters = model.coef_
predicted_classes = model.predict(X)
accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted_genre.flatten(),predicted_classes)
```

This is the error I observe:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-1b8359fe335e> in <module>
     12 #model.fit(df1, predicted_genre)
     13 X = np.c_[np.ones((df1.shape[0], 1)), df1]
---> 14 predicted_genre = predicted_genre[:, np.newaxis]
     15 theta = np.zeros((X.shape[1], 1))
     16 model = LogisticRegression()
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
/srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2485         """Return the cached item, item represents a label indexer."""
   2486         cache = self._item_cache
-> 2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
   2489             values = self._data.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

When not including this line: `predicted_genre = predicted_genre[:, np.newaxis]` I get this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError 
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-49-0fede056d645> 
in <module> 
18 parameters = model.coef_ 
19 predicted_classes = model.predict(X) ---> 
20 accuracy = accuracy_score(predicted_genre.flatten(),predicted_classes) 
21 parameters /srv/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name) 4374 if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name): 4375 return self[name] -> 4376 return object.__getattribute__(self, name) 4377 4378 def __setattr__(self, name, value): AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a `pandas` error, not an sklearn one; I kindly suggest you remove all code that comes after the error (it is never executed, hence irrelevant), as well as all irrelevant imports - cleaner code is easier and more attractive to possible respondents,

Comment: @desertnaut thank you for the note, I adjusted the code accordingly